# Catch SQLException from a stored procedure IN a gridview

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure(SP) named UPDATE_INFO, in that SP, I throw some SQLExceptions

```
RAISERROR ('Exception Created',16,1);
```

I use that SP in a girdview, now what I want is that whenever an exception is thrown, I can catch it and display it sothat the users can know what is going wrong.

But I don't know how to do this, I think that the Gridview already catch all exceptions from SPs

Does anyone get a way to do this?

Code part:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePane" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate >
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProjectID" 
        DataSourceID="DataSource" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" CausesValidation="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"
                SortExpression="ProjectID"/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource" runat="server" 
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">

        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call the stored procedure in your code and how you bind the results to the GridView? Then we can help :)

Comment: added :D do you need the SP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the OnRowUpdated event and detect if there were any errors like this:

```
protected void GridView_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            //show nice error message however you want
            // I imagine by firing javascript on the page
            e.ExceptionHandled = true; //important not forgetting this
        }
}
```

In your markup:

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView" OnRowUpdated="GridView_RowUpdated" runat="server"` AllowPaging="True"  ....

Answer (score 1):

Man, you are doing everything in the aspx page. In general these things are done in the code behind where you can use ADO.NET with more control on what happens and you can invoke the stored procedure inside a try-catch.

Probably there is also a way to set the exception handling event to trigger from the aspx markup page you are using but I do think is better if you load the data from  method in the `aspx.cs` file.

this is what is usually done in real world applications.